# Start of the First Day

Tags: hunt-for-the-ring

**Do effects that occur at the start of a day happen at the beginning of the first turn?**

**Does the Fellowship player draw two (due to Pippin being in play) additional cards at the start of the first turn, as they would during a Refresh Step?**  My assumption is ***no***, since most of what happens during a Refresh Step is explicitly spelled out in the Setup instructions, implying to me that there is no actual Refresh Step at the start of the first turn.

**Does the Lead Nazgul player draw an extra Sorcery card as they would during the Refresh Step?**  Again, I assume ***no*** for the same reasons above, although it does seem strange to me that the first player misses out on this card draw.

**Does Frodo's passive ability trigger, which causes him to draw a Fellowship Token if he has less than 2 already (which is true)?**  I assume ***yes***, as it is "the beginning of a new day", which does not seem to interact with the Refresh Step or be otherwise ambiguous.